# What happened to the Muggle bank manager that Newt Scamander Petrified?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts

If I remember correctly, Newt casts *Petrificus Totalus* on a <s>No-Maj</s> Muggle [bank manager](http://www.hierarchystructure.com/bank-employee-hierarchy/).

The guy obviously knew what was happening, seeing that he muttered a strained "Kowalski" while Petrified. I'd expect that the flash of light from Newt's wand was obvious too.

**What happened to him? Was he Obliviated immediately after or at all?**

Comment: They used him as a doorstop.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The bank manager in question is [Mr Bingley](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/mr-bingley/).

Mr Bingley retains his memories of the 'bank robbery' and his experience with the *Full Body-Bind Curse* until the end of the movie (about 2 days in movie time) when [Frank the Thunderbird](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/frank/) dispersed [*Swooping Evil venom*](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/creature/swooping-evil/) over New York.

Mr Bingely was in the shower at the time, and subsequently lost all of his memories of the past few days.

[image: Mr Bingely in the shower, losing his memories.]

Taken from the script of [Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them: The Original Screenplay](https://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/fantastic-beasts-and-where-to-find-them-j-k-rowling/1123722904) ([found online here](https://perksofbeinganasiangirl.files.wordpress.com/2015/10/fantastic-beasts-the-original-screenplay.pdf)):

> Mr. Bingley, the bank manager, stands in his bathroom taking a
>   shower. As the water trickles over him, he too is Obliviated. We
>   see Bingley’s wife, brushing her teeth, her expression vacant,
>   carefree.

Comment: So *that's* who the guy in the shower was. Great find - accepted.

Comment: Only thing that would make that better is if the wife **saw the obliviator** and said "Hi Liza." And the obliviator said "Hi Jane."