# What happened to the Muggles who were home or away?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, fantastic-beasts-where-to-find-them

During *Fantastic Beasts and Where To Find Them*, plenty of Muggles come to learn "a lot" about the wizarding world. This was solved when Frank the Thunderbird dispersed Swooping Evil venom over New York.

However, this fell as rainfall and umbrellas seemed to be able to stop it (magical ones at least). It also shows that it apparently [got into the water](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/162331/what-happened-to-the-muggle-bank-manager-that-newt-petrified) 
as the bank manager is inside showering but appears to have had his memory "wiped".

There would have been people inside or even not in New York anymore. It would make sense that some of these wouldn't have come into contact with the rainfall. So what happened to these people?

Were their memories wiped some other way? Were they hunted down by the Ministry and wiped? Or did some even manage to live on with the memory of it all?

Comment: Since they were now a minority, like any minority they were labeled as weirdos and taken aways by the good people in white coats. And they were never seen again.

Comment: @Gallifreyan I did think of that as well just forgot to put it in the question. But would like to see if there is any evidence of what actually happened too.

Comment: I’m reopening because this is a question about what would happen to Muggles who witnessed magic and then *never* touched the water in any way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Once they’re found, they’d be handled by the Obliviators.

It wouldn’t be a problem if there were a few Muggles who left New York and didn’t come into contact with the Swooping Evil venom in the rain. There would be a much smaller number of them, so they can be handled in the typical way. Usually, the Obliviators handle the Muggles who witness magic. The only reason they couldn’t after the Obscurus wreaked havoc throughout New York was because there were simply too many people who needed to be Obliviated for them to feasibly handle - there was an entire densely populated city of Muggles they’d have to Obliviate.

> “MADAM PICQUERY
>
> We owe you an apology, Mr Scamander. But the magical community is exposed! We cannot Obliviate an entire city.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them: The Original Screenplay*</sup></sub>

When it’s not the entire city of New York, when there are Muggles who witnessed magic, the Obliviators are able to handle it. They can manage fairly large numbers of people had Obliviated all of the Second Salemers after Tina used magic on Mary Lou Barebone in front of them.

> “NEWT
>
> (realising)
>
> And she was the No-Maj you attacked?
>
> TINA
>
> That’s how I lost my job. I went for her in front of a meeting of her crazy followers – they all had to be Obliviated. It was a big scandal.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them: The Original Screenplay*</sup></sub>

The Swooping Evil venom Obliviated the vast majority of Muggles who needed to be - MACUSA would just have their Obliviators handle anyone who was somehow missed by the venom.

## A few might not get Obliviated, but they’d be thought mad.

It is theoretically possible that MACUSA could miss a few stray Muggles and not Obliviate them, but even if they did, those few would be thought mad by other Muggles and dismissed as lunatics. Newt himself mentioned this in his book *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*.

> “There can be no doubt that the overwhelming majority of present-day Muggles refuse to believe in the magical beasts their ancestors so feared. Even those Muggles who do notice Porlock droppings or Streeler trails – it would be foolish to suppose that all traces of these creatures can be hidden – appear satisfied with the flimsiest non-magical explanation.8 If any Muggle is unwise enough to confide in another that he has spotted a Hippogriff winging its way north, he is generally believed to be drunk or a “loony.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*</sup></sub>

Even if MACUSA missed a few Muggles, those few Muggles wouldn’t be believed, they’d just be considered lunatics by the Muggle community, and the existence of wizards would remain secret.